# Gostaria de entender por que quando o ModelState é invalido, a instanciação da ViewModel é "ignorada" e os campos do formulário continuam populados?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc, asp.net-core, viewmodel

Segue meu código:

Model de Subcategoria

```
public class SubCategoria
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo {0} é obrigatório")]
    [StringLength(200, ErrorMessage = "Campo {0} precisa ter entre {2} e {1} caracteres ", MinimumLength = 2)]
    public string Titulo { get; set; }

    public Categoria Categoria { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Livro> Livros { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel de Subcategoria:

```
public class SubcategoriaViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo {0} é obrigatório")]
    [StringLength(200, ErrorMessage = "Campo {0} precisa ter entre {2} e {1} caracteres ", MinimumLength = 2)]
    public string Titulo { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CategoriaId { get; set; }
}
```

Nosso controller (uma parte) de "Subcategoria"

```
    // GET: SubCategorias/Create
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        var vm = new SubcategoriaViewModel();
        ViewData["CategoriaId"] = new SelectList(_context.Categorias, "Id", "Titulo");
        return View(vm);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(SubcategoriaViewModel subCategoriaVM)
    { 
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var subcategoria = new SubCategoria
            {
                Titulo = subCategoriaVM.Titulo,
                Categoria = _context.Categorias.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == subCategoriaVM.CategoriaId)
            };
            _context.Add(subcategoria);
             await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return Create();
```

Quando o meu ModelState é invalido, o browser continua na tela de create com os campos preenchidos.

Minha duvida é em relação a isso - como isso é possível se no Create() (GET) sempre instancio uma nova ViewModel?
Se eu instancio uma nova ViewModel, a lógica não era voltar o formulário vazio?

Enfim...
Gostaria de entender por que quando o ModelState é invalido a instanciação da ViewModel é "ignorada" e os campos do formulário continuam populados?

Answer (score 0):

Estranho, isso só deveria acontecer caso tivesses a retornar `return View(subCategoriaVM);`.

No entanto, podes utilizar o método `ModelState.Clear();` que deverá resolver o problema.